# Compute the product

Tags: calculus, infinite-product

Compute $\prod_{0<i<j<\infty} i^{1/i} - j^{1/j}$. Here are a few steps I tried. Have no clue from which angle to solve it.

Maybe we need to factor the term $i^{1/i} - j^{1/j} = j^{1/j}(i^{1/i}j^{-1/j}-1)=j^{1/j}((i/j)^{1/i}j^{1/i-1/j}-1)$.

Maybe we should rewrite it as a summation of log.

But still lack of ideas.

Comment: Where did you find this problem?

Comment: @FShrike From a friend. No idea its background....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: What happens when $i=2$ and $j=4$.

Comment: That'll be zero. It seems sufficient to conclude it is zero because all terms are finite... Thank you~